# Rasbberrypi - picamera not working

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have installed the picamera package and when i try to run the following program, i end up with an error.

```
Code:import time
     import picamera
     with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
         camera.start_preview()
         time.sleep(2)
         camera.stop_preview()
```

Error: 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Picamera'

Please do suggest on resolving the above error.

Regards,
Richi

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should update your installation with command
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
and enable camera port using 
    sudo raspi-config

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me too. My script was as simple as this

```
import picamera

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.capture('test.jpg')
```

tried everything - from updating to rewriting the script. Always got

`AttributeError: 'module' object has not attribute 'PiCamera'`

raspberry pi camera was functioning fine (`raspistill -o testshot.jpg`worked fine)

tried on python shell and that too gave the same error!?! - suprising was it was mentioning the filename (camera.py) although I was not running a file - i was in the python shell!

I just deleted the file lest i go insane - it worked perfect fine then. Sometimes these machines get brain farts

Answer (score 0):

Please check your OS. If you have 64-bit OS you can't use Picamera and you should install picamera2.

If there is no problem with your OS and picamera. You should check your camera. The first thing you should check is your ribbon cable and many of the problems are with the ribbon cable maybe you connect the ribbon cable wrong to the camera slot and maybe you connect the ribbon cable to the wrong slot and Raspberry has 2 slot one.

If your ribbon cable has no problem. Please write this command in your terminal : `vcgencmd get_camera`